# (C programming) Writing the Leibniz method using a WHILE loop

Tags: c

The purpose of my assignment is to create a FOR loop that performs the circle method of getting pi and a WHILE loop that performs the Leibniz method for approximating Pi. I have no idea where to start for the Leibniz method because I don't understand what expression to put in the while loop to make it work. Please help me.

> This method approximates pi by using a formula derived by Gottfried
> Leibniz, also known as "the father of calculus." This method uses an
> infinite series of additions and subtractions to approximate pi:
>
> π/4 = 1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9 - 1/11 + . . .
>
> Notice that this approximates pi / 4. After the summation of the
> terms, you need to multiply the value by 4 to arrive at the final
> approximation. Analogous to the circle method, the more terms in the
> series, the closer the approximation of pi: (Example)
>
> ### Iterations      Leibniz Method
>
> ```
>      1      4.000000000000
>     10      3.041839618929
>    100      3.131592903559
>   1000      3.140592653840
>  10000      3.141492653590
> 100000      3.141582653590
> ```

**I have already completed the circle method for loop, and it works on its own.** It's the while loop that the focus should be on.

```
double circle_pi(int rectangles)
{
 double radius = 2.0;
 long i;
 long double width = radius / (long double)rectangles;
 long double rect_area = 0.0;
 long double midpoint, height;
 midpoint = width / 2.0;

for(i = 1; i <= rectangles; i++)
{
 height = sqrt((radius * radius) - (midpoint * midpoint));
 midpoint = midpoint + width;
 rect_area = rect_area + width * height;
 }
 
return rect_area;
}

double leibniz_pi(int iterations)
{

  while()
  {
    /* code */
   }
  return 
}
```

This is my driver.c code to go with it. I cannot make changes to it.

````
double circle_pi(int rectangles);  /* Calculates PI using a quarter circle */
double leibniz_pi(int iterations); /* Calculates PI using a series         */

int main(void)
{
  int i; /* loop counter */

    /* Print out table header */
  printf("Approximations for pi\n");
  printf("Iterations      Circle Method   Leibniz Method\n");
  printf("----------------------------------------------\n");

    /* Print out values for each set of numbers */
  for (i = 1; i <= 1000000; i *= 10)
  {
      /* Calculate PI with both methods */
    double pi_circle = circle_pi(i);
    double pi_leibniz = leibniz_pi(i);

      /* Print the results of the calculations */
    printf("%10i%20.12f%16.12f\n", i, pi_circle, pi_leibniz);
  }

  return 0; /* Return success to the OS */
}```
````

Comment: *"I don't understand what expression to put in the while loop"* Hint: the same as the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

The Leibniz method subtracts and adds fractions with odd denominators alternately.

Thus, our code will look something like the following:

```c
int count = 0;
int iters = 10000;

double pi_4 = 0;

while (count < iters) {
    if (count % 2 == 0) {
        // On "even" counts (where our fraction is 1/1, 1/5, 1/9..., add)
        pi_4 += 1.0 / (1.0 + 2 * count);
    else {
        // On "odd" counts (where our fraction is 1/3, 1/7, 1/11..., subtract)
        pi_4 -= 1.0 / (1.0 + 2 * count);
    }
    count++;
}
return 4 * pi_4;
```